# JTextField flashing white when typing

Tags: java, swing, rendering

I am actively rendering using a BufferStrategy in my own render loop. Here is the method that takes care of the repainting.

```
public void handleRepaint() {
    try {
        Graphics g = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
        render(g);
        g.dispose();
        if (!buffer.contentsLost()) {
            buffer.show();
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    }
}
```

The details of the `render(Graphics g)` method are a bit unnecessary to display. Basically I am doing my custom repainting, and then calling `contentPane.paintComponents(Graphics g)`, with the `contentPane` being the content pane of my `JFrame`, cast into a `JComponent`.

This works perfectly when the components are opaque. However, when any component is transparent, weird things start to happen. For example, if I create a `JButton` and add it to the `JPanel`, the background of the button occasionally flashes white when the mouse enters/exists it. When I add a `JTextField`, typing will occasionally cause the entire text field to flash white.

I can't figure out what is going on. It obviously has something to do with the active rendering, but I can't figure out what it is. Even with [the tutorial I used](http://jamesgames.org/resources/double_buffer/double_buffering_and_active_rendering.html), the same thing happens when I set any of their `JButtons` to be transparent.

I'm at a loss as to how to fix this problem. With the buttons, disabling the rollover works, but I don't want the rollover to be disabled. And with `JTextFields` and other components, there is no rollover to be disabled, and I can't just disable typing.

So if anyone has a solution to this, please help.

PS: The repaint code for the swing components are all run on the EDT.

Comment: Mixing heavy and light weight components in this manner, especially using BufferStrategy isn't highly recommended. AWT based components don't respond well to transparency....

Comment: Yes, but you were even the one who recommended the tutorial to me originally.

However, if that is the case, would you recommend using strictly AWT components?

Comment: Yes. As I said before, Swing components simply aren't designed to work this way...

Answer (score 0):

> However, when any component is transparent, weird things start to happen.

Whenever I see a comment like that I suggest you check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for potential problems and a couple of solutions.

Basically, because the background is transparent you need to make the component non-opaque so its parents background is painted first, then you need to do custom painting to paint your components background.